# Rails test for current_path not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My rspec test is failing due to the test not matching the correct url path. However, when I check it manually in my browser it works correctly.

My test looks like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Photography jobs" do

    context "as a user" do

        scenario "adds a new photography job" do
            user = create(:user)
            signin(user.email, user.password)
            visit root_path
            click_link "Add Job"

            fill_in "Name", with: "Joe Blow"
            fill_in "Email", with: "joe@hotmail.com"
            fill_in "Session Date", with: "9/24/1978"
            fill_in "Location", with: "North Shore"
            fill_in "Notes", with: "Requested this date."
            click_button "Submit"

            expect(current_path).to eq job_path
            expect(page).to have_content "Session was successfully created."
            expect(page).to have_content "North Shore"
            expect(page).to have_content "9/24/1978"
        end

    end

end
```

The controller looks like:

```
    def new
      @job = Job.new
    end

    def create
      @job = Job.new(job_params)
      @job.user = current_user
      if @job.save
        redirect_to @job, notice: 'Session was successfully created.' 
      else
        flash[:error] = @job.errors.full_messages
        flash[:errors_list] = @job.errors.messages
        redirect_to new_job_path(@job)
      end  
    end
```

The error when I run rspec spec/features is:

```
 1) Photography jobs as a user adds a new photography job
     Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq job_path
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"jobs"} missing required keys: [:id]
     # ./spec/features/new_jobs_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
expect(current_path).to eq job_path
```

it must be something like `job_path(@job)` but since you are creating a new job record with `submit` so you can't do that test here because the job record doesn't have its `:id` till it is persisted in your database.

I think it is good to do that kind of test in controller spec but in feature spec.
For feature spec here, just

```
click_button "Submit"

expect(page).to have_content "Session was successfully created."
expect(page).to have_content "North Shore"
expect(page).to have_content "9/24/1978"
```

is fine.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I was trying to think how I would get the saved job id but it didn't make sense. I'll try to move that test into a controller spec.